# How do you ask about job position number one after interviewing for job position number two?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, new-job, job-change

I'm more interested in position one but got an interview for position two. I would like to have a shot at position one, so how do I ask about the application status of position one when I just got interviewed for position two. Position two is more of a back up if I don't get position one. They'er making a decision this week and I'm likely getting the job. How do I professionally tell them that I want an interview for position one before making my decision?

Comment: did you apply for both position one and position two?

Comment: Yes, I applied to both at the same time.

Comment: Are position one and two at the same company? And were you already interviewed for position one?

Answer (score 5):

Talk to the hiring manager/recruiter and say words to the effect:

"I see that you are also advertising for Position One, I think my skills and experience would also be a good fit for this role and I'm interested in interviewing for it"

It's not uncommon for this sort of scenario, so it's not considered rude.

Answer (score 1):

Since you applied for both and they only interviewed you for one of them (as opposed to ghosting you), I think they probably don't see you as a good match for position one.

You could reach out to HR or recruiting to follow-up on the status of your application for position one.

Before you push to hard on position one, think about how much you like the company and position two.

If you only want position one, then pursue that directly and let them know that.

If you would take position two and like the company, I wouldn't push too hard on position one because they might feel you don't really want position two and you could lose that opportunity.  You could check with HR about internal mobility and consider taking position two and decide later whether to pursue position one through an internal move later.